# Frustum in Three.js

Tags: three.js

In OpenGL Geometry is always clipped against the boundaries of a six plane frustum in x, y, and z. Three.js57 also have the Frustum with six plane. I want know how to achieve clip
the mesh in three.js using three.js frustum

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe Constructive Solid Geometry (CSG) is an option that will work for you. See http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/12/10/constructive-solid-geometry-with-csg-js/. The libraries may no longer be compatible with the current version of three.js, however.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the following parameter in the three.js documentation. It seems that geometry will be checked against the frustum by it.

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Object3D

If `.frustumCulled` is set to true, it checks every frame if the object is in the frustum of the camera.